# How to insert files as arguments

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to pass in two text files as arguments but my program cannot find them. The files that i am trying to pass in are located in the same file as my project but is not inside my project folder. [Image of file configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuJrA.png)

I have tried entering the text files as, "../COSC485_P1_DFA.txt" "../COSC485_P1_Strings.txt"

```
if(args.length != 2){
            System.out.println("ERROR, input agrument is incorrect. Please try again");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        File automataFile = new File(args[0].substring(1, args[0].length() - 1));
        File stringFile = new File(args[1].substring(1, args[1].length() - 1));

        if(automataFile.exists()== false){
            System.out.println("automata file doesnt exist");
        }
        if(stringFile.exists()== false){
            System.out.println("string file doesnt exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

The two if statements at the end of the code I provided should not do the print out statements. Right now they are printing out meaning the program cannot find the two files.

Comment: Well, have you tried moving them into your project folder ? Or otherwise, use absolute paths ?

Comment: Where are the files in relation to where you are running the program from?

Comment: Why do you remove the first and last characters of the file path? Do some basic debugging: print the arguments you're receiving. Print the absolute path of the files. Check if it's correct. Remember that the location of your project is basically irrelevant. What matters for relative file paths is the *current* directory, which is the directory from which you execute the java command.

Comment: I got it. when creating the files like I did above, I was able to just use args[0] and args[1]. For my text files I used ../filename.txt